# How to cross-compile for Android without cmakelists.txt?

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I know that if a C++ project has CMakeLists.txt, I can create a new project and use Android studio to compile the executable to run on Android via console.
However, some projects don't have CMakeList.txt and need to run . /configure and then make. e.g. https://github.com/strukturag/libheif
Is there a easy tool that can compile it for Android on Windows?

Comment: This is covered in the [Android NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems#autoconf)

Comment: I am confused. Your linked example has a CMakeLists.txt. With that said I don't yet build for Android so I may be missing something.

Comment: @Botje  Thanks. I will try it. But I found “Caution: Autoconf projects are generally not buildable on Windows. Windows users can build these projects using the Windows Subsystem for Linux or a Linux VM.” , so there is no way for windows native tool?

Comment: Well, the library you linked to *does* have a CMakeLists.txt, but you could try getting by with a mingw or msys install... Then again, you only need to do this once. I would personally just build this in a Docker container and commit the resulting binaries to your repository.

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes that you have mingw installed and also a cross-compiler compatible with your platform. Also, I'm not a big fan of Windows for this type of development. So my explanation is for Linux. But **I believe** you can easily adapt it to your case.

First of all, you need to install a cross-compiler. For the sake of explanation, I'm going to use gcc-linaro here.

If you open the repo, you'll see that there is a file called **autogen.sh**.
You will need to run it. This file will create the configuration tool.
Once it finishes, a file called **configure** will appear.
This is the tool you want to use for configuring the library to be compiled, customized for your specific needs.

The next command you want to run is

```
./configure --help
```

The above command will show you all the options that you can set. You can play with them but, typically, you want to set the following, at least:

- CC
- --prefix
- --includedir
- --libdir
- --host

These options are explained in the configure tool. To give you an idea on how to use them, the following is the generic command that you might want to run:

```
CC="<path to your gcc compiler>" ./configure --prefix="<path_to_the_folder_where_you_want_to_install>" --includedir="<path_to_the_include_dir>" --libdir="<path_to_the_lib_dir>" --host=arm
```

In my situation, I have installed the cross compiler at the following path

```
/home/alexis/gcc-linaro/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

Therefore, I would need to run the command:

```
CC="/home/alexis/gcc-linaro/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc" ./configure --prefix=/home/alexis/gcc-linaro --includedir=/home/alexis/gcc-linaro/include --libdir=/home/alexis/gcc-linaro/lib --host=arm
```

Hope this helps.